# Getting $content of content type in template.php

Tags: nodes, theming

I am trying to get form that is used in content type template in template.php.
I am creating node collections with EntityFieldQuery, and I am pulling field values of content type without problem.

But i need to access form, and add it to html stream that i create in template.php

In content type i can do

```
print render($content['add_to_cart']);
```

To get form out.

But now in **template.php** i need that form for specific nodes (im pulling them with EntityFieldQuery) as html, so i can include it to rest of the stream and send the  data in variable, and simply output it where i need it (content type page.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure, if this is what you are looking. But if you want to embed a node-add form you could use the following code.

```
<?php
$node = new stdClass();
$node->type = 'machine_name_of_your_content_type';
module_load_include('inc', 'node', 'node.pages');
$output = drupal_get_form('machine_name_of_your_content_type_node_form', $node);
print $output;
?>
```

Comment: I did not test it, but it seems like correct answer, as it gets all the form in $output variable (i hope :) )

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to aerozeppelin, i implemented it this way:

in template.php
($node is fetched via EntityFieldQuery)

```
$add_to_cart = array( '#theme' => 'uc_product_add_to_cart',
'#form' => drupal_get_form('uc_product_add_to_cart_form_' . $node->nid, $node), );
$cart_form = drupal_render($add_to_cart);
```

where $cart_form contains html data form, that i included in my data stream!

Comment: and i also looked here: http://www.excellentwebworld.com/add-to-cart-form-on-other-pages-in-ubercart-for-drupla-67/